# Problems positioning/resizing background image

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having difficulties in the header to resize/position a div with a background image.I did some google searches, but nothing really helped me..

The header has a logo, which is in a div called "header-left-section". On the top right of the logo, there is a navigation menu aligned within a div called "header-right-section". Those divs were already present in the theme.
We now wanted an image below the navigation menu and also on the right side of the logo. For that, I created a div tag "bottom-header-section" and set the image as the background image. Now I read several topics, that the background image doesnt show if there isnt a height and width set to it because therefor the div wouldnt have a size.

Now my problem is, that as soon as I make my browser window smaller, the div with the background image is set bellow the logo and menu, which I dont want at all.

This is my divs css code:

```html
#bottom-header-section {    
background-image: url('website/wertesystem/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/title-new.png');
    float:left;
    height: 120px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: inherit;
    background-position: right bottom; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
```

With my understanding, now that I set the height to 120px and the width to 800px, this I set a fixed size to the div and as soon as I make the window smaller, the div keeps the same size but changes position because there isn't any more space on the same line as before right?

So what's the best way to align this div, on the right side of the logo and keep it responsive?

If you need a link to the website, please just tell me.

Comment: Could you send a link to the site please

Comment: yes, sure! http://www.c9w.at/wertesystem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add something like this for the smaller breakpoint.

```
#bottom-header-section {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65%;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

You might have to play with the height and width as it gets smaller.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks so much!! You dont believe how much that helped me! :) Do you know any websites where I can view my websites for smaller screens? My friend keeps complaining that he cant see the full slider on the front page on his 13'' screen but I can see it perfectly when resizing the window..

Comment: No worries, glad to help. I use a product called browser stack to test but that is a paid for service. Resizing the browser should work fine as the changes are only css. It could be a problem with the browser they are using. You could always view the website on your phone to see what it looks like.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Yeah thats a good guess. As far as I know he uses a macbook so he might used Safari... I'll check it out next time I meet up with him. Thanks again!